# JDeveloper 11g JAX-RPC Web Service Client Unable to Parse WSDL

Tags: web-services, jdeveloper, jax-rpc

We're trying to migrate a JDev 10g to 11g project. We had some old JAX-RPC clients created that had to upgraded, which didn't work, so I recreated the clients in JDev 11g using the Web Service Client wizard (based off of the service WSDL, default settings for everything).

I created them and when I try to use it I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: Failed to parse WSDL
at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.setCallbackServiceQName(ServiceImpl.java:333)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.checkWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:286)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.init(ServiceImpl.java:159)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.<init>
```

This is odd because the WSDL that it's failing to parse is the created one that it made from the Wizard.

```
public J140_Item_Service_Impl(String wsdlurl, weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.TransportInfo transportInfo) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    super(wsdlurl,
          new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.amc.com/schemas/1/if/J140_Item", "J140_Item"),
          "amc/schemas/j140_item/j140_Item_Service_internaldd.xml", transportInfo);
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error too, I could not figure out the root cause, however I recreated the client with ws format instead of `rpc` and it worked for me.